# Unable to determine whether something is a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm wondering how I can tell if a transformation $\sf T$ is a matrix transformation, for example:

Determine whether $\sf T$ is a matrix transformation or not:
a: ${\sf T}(x,y,z) = (0,0)$
b: ${\sf T}(x,y,z,w) = (1,-1)$
c: ${\sf T}(x,y,z) = (x - y + z, 0)$

I am really not able to see how I could decide that, any simple explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A linear transformation, not a matrix transformation.

Comment: I know the properties of a linear transformation, but I keep hearing about matrix transformation and so I am left clueless of how to attack the question at hand.

Thank you for your comment

Comment: I would say a linear transformation is a function that maps from a domain to a codomain in a linear fashion. It has to follow these rules:
"a" and "b" are vectors
T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b), and
T(ca) = cT(a)

Comment: Define a "matrix transformation"

Comment: That, I have no clue @KennyLau

Comment: Then you are asking an ill-defined question

Comment: That could be, I wasn't sure on how to attack this one, so I thought I'd give it this approach. Would you be so kind of giving an explanation of a matrix transformation, in comparrison to a linear one, or by it self.

Comment: To be kind, I'll treat a number as a $1\times1$ "matrix".

Answer (score 1):

You state in the comments that a linear transformation is one that satisfies \begin{align*}
T(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}) &= T(\mathbf{v}) + T(\mathbf{w})\\
T(c\mathbf{v}) &= cT(\mathbf{v})
\end{align*}
for arbitrary vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ and arbitrary scalar $c$. This is indeed the common definition. "Matrix transformation" is not standard terminology in mathematics, but may well be in applied fields (such as computer science) and surely means "transformation that acts by matrix multiplication," which is a linear transformation.

So, you check these properties: for case (a), we take two arbitrary vectors $\mathbf{v}=(x_1,y_1,z_1); \mathbf{w} =(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and compute
$$T(\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}) = T(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2) = (0,0)$$
$$T(\mathbf{v}) + T(\mathbf{w}) = T(x_1,y_1,z_1) + T(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (0,0) + (0,0) = (0,0)$$
so the first property checks out.

Can you check the second property of part (a), and complete the rest of the assignment, yourself?